# How to track Facebook App Invites

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that utilizes the App Invite feature shown here https://developers.facebook.com/products/sharing/app-invites.

I would like to run a contest on who shares the app the most. Is there a way I can track who shares my app the most? When a user shares, he/she has the option to multi-select as many Facebook friends as they want. I would like to see:

a) who they have invited

b) if (a) not possible, how many people they invited

c) if (b) not possible, when the invitee installs the app, give credit to who invited them.

Please let me know if that make sense. I don't mind using third party SDK's if necessary.

Comment: You are not allowed to reward people for sending out invites – you are at most allowed to reward them for _successful_ invites, i.e. when one of their friends joins your app upon their invite. See https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse, 4.5

Comment: you got users  who install your app

Comment: @CBroe that is completely fine. I can definitely do that. I would just like to know who to reward.

Comment: There’s something in the requests documentation about that … although it only describes the process for users following the invite to canvas; I am not sure if that works for an iOS app in a similar way.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios. See Dynamic App Link endpoint.

Comment: Did you have any success to get the friends a user has invited? I need the same since we need performance tracking for the usage of this invite feature.

Comment: @blackjacx unfortunately not. If you figure it out let me know too please.